# creation of Manufacturing Order from Sale Order

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I know the functional flow of the `sale order` in which a `MO` is created for a product that is configured to be manufactured in `product master`

Below I have descried in brief the Functional flow:

when we create a product and set it as manufacturing we then create a `BOM` for that respective `product`, which results in the creation of a `Manufacturing Order` after confirming a `sale order` for that product, and the `origin` field in `MO` contains the `sale order` name too.

My question is, Which Method in the backend is responsible for the creation of `MO` from `sale order`? actually, the `MO` is created in the `confirmed` state and I want it to be created in `draft` when it is created from `Sale Order`. so I like to know which `method` is responsible for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manufacture Orders are created as part of the procurement planning system by the Stock Rule object in the method called `_run_manufacture`

Link to the line where the confirmation takes place.
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7ec6ae3863da4c7355c4a22ef799815a38188402/addons/mrp/models/stock_rule.py#L55

Comment: i have already got that method and completed it, thanks for your reply.